# Avoiding duplcate posts on the main page

Tags: posts

I have several pages on my site. Each of them displays posts belonging to a certain category. For example, the “Recipes” page displays only posts from the “Recipes” category, the “Jokes” page displays only posts from the “Jokes” category, and so on. The main page displays posts from all the categories. Suddenly I noticed that there are duplicate posts on the main page. For example, the “Recipe 1” post appears there 2 times. Both of these posts have the same address.

Interestingly, these posts are not repeated in the “Recipes” category, they are only repeated on the main page. Why does it happen? I tried different themes but no luck. On another forum I was advised to insert the following section at the end of `functions.php` file, but it didn't help.

```php
add_filter('post_link', 'track_displayed_posts');
add_action('pre_get_posts','remove_already_displayed_posts');
 
$displayed_posts = [];
 
function track_displayed_posts($url) {
  global $displayed_posts;
  $displayed_posts[] = get_the_ID();
  return $url; // don't mess with the url
}
 
function remove_already_displayed_posts($query) {
 global $displayed_posts;
 $query->set('post__not_in', $displayed_posts);
}
```

Here are the contents of my functions.php file.

```
<?php
/**
 * NewsBook functions and definitions
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/
 *
 * @package NewsBook
 */

if ( ! defined( 'NEWSBOOK_VERSION' ) ) {
    // Theme version.
    $newsbook_theme = wp_get_theme();
    define( 'NEWSBOOK_VERSION', $newsbook_theme->get( 'Version' ) );
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'newsbook_setup' ) ) :
    /**
     * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
     *
     * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
     * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such
     * as indicating support for post thumbnails.
     */
    function newsbook_setup() {
        /*
         * Make theme available for translation.
         * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory.
         * If you're building a theme based on NewsBook, use a find and replace
         * to change 'newsbook' to the name of your theme in all the template files.
         */
        load_theme_textdomain( 'newsbook', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

        // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
        add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

        /*
         * Let WordPress manage the document title.
         * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
         * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
         * provide it for us.
         */
        add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

        /*
         * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
         *
         * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/
         */
        add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

        // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
        register_nav_menus(
            array(
                'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'newsbook' ),
            )
        );

        /*
         * Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments
         * to output valid HTML5.
         */
        add_theme_support(
            'html5',
            array(
                'search-form',
                'comment-form',
                'comment-list',
                'gallery',
                'caption',
                'style',
                'script',
            )
        );

        // Set up the WordPress core custom background feature.
        add_theme_support(
            'custom-background',
            apply_filters(
                'newsbook_custom_background_args',
                array(
                    'default-color' => 'edf2f7',
                    'default-image' => '',
                )
            )
        );

        // Define image sizes for theme.
        add_image_size( 'newsbook-featured-image', 1020, 600, true );
        add_image_size( 'newsbook-featured-image-medium', 500, 300, true );
        add_image_size( 'newsbook-featured-image-small', 150, 120, true );

        // Add theme support for selective refresh for widgets.
        add_theme_support( 'customize-selective-refresh-widgets' );

        /**
         * Add support for core custom logo.
         *
         * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Logo
         */
        add_theme_support(
            'custom-logo',
            array(
                'flex-width'  => true,
                'flex-height' => true,
            )
        );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'newsbook_setup' );

/**
 * Set the content width in pixels, based on the theme's design and stylesheet.
 *
 * Priority 0 to make it available to lower priority callbacks.
 *
 * @global int $content_width
 */
function newsbook_content_width() {
    $GLOBALS['content_width'] = apply_filters( 'newsbook_content_width', 1020 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'newsbook_content_width', 0 );

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function newsbook_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'newsbook-fonts', '//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap', array(), NEWSBOOK_VERSION );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-5-grid', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap-grid.css', array(), 'v5.0.0-alpha1', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'newsbook-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), NEWSBOOK_VERSION );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'newsbook-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js', array(), NEWSBOOK_VERSION, true );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'newsbook_scripts' );

/**
 * Implement the Custom Header feature.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php';

/**
 * Custom template tags for this theme.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

/**
 * Functions which enhance the theme by hooking into WordPress.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-functions.php';

/**
 * Functions which enhance the theme by hooking into WordPress.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/header-functions.php';

/**
 * Functions which enhance the theme by hooking into WordPress.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/footer-functions.php';

/**
 * Functions which enhance the theme by hooking into WordPress.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/frontpage-functions.php';

/**
 * Customizer additions.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';

/**
 * Add new widgets.
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/widgets.php';

/**
 * Load Jetpack compatibility file.
 */
if ( defined( 'JETPACK__VERSION' ) ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/jetpack.php';
}
```

Comment: How are your posts being shown on the main page? Your `$displayed_posts` variable isn't a global variable everywhere you use it, it has to be declared as global in every scope or you'll have separate variables that are and aren't global. It's not enough to say `global` once. Also `post__not_in` is extremely slow and expensive, it's much more efficient to filter the post out in PHP ( or specify which zone on the homepage it should be in via a taxonomy and force it to only have one term assigned. There's also no guarantee any of this will work as there's zero info about how they're shown

Comment: I edited my question to include the contents of my functions.php file.

Comment: that tells me nothing about how your homepage is displayed, is it a page template? Page builder output? A `home.php`? `front-page.php`? Is it the main loop or a custom loop or custom loops?

Comment: ok it looks like this is the 3rd party theme newsbook from https://wordpress.org/themes/newsbook/, have you raised this on their support forum? 3rd party theme dev support is off topic here

Comment: and the area in question is a widget sidebar https://themes.svn.wordpress.org/newsbook/1.0.5/front-page.php, the code you tried to use will be useless if any of this is cached